# $X$ is complete iff $\partial B(0,1)$ is complete.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let X be a normed $\mathbb K$-linear space .Prove that $X$ is complete if and only if $\partial B(0,1)$  is complete with respect to the metric induced  by the norm.

I hve done the $(\implies)$ part. Since $\partial B(0,1)$ is closed  subset of a complete metric space so it will be complte. But I am stuck to solve the converse part $(\impliedby)$.

Please someone help.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence. Then $\{\|x_n\|\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. 
If $\|x_n\|\to 0$, then $x_n$  converges to $0$.
If $\|x_n\|\to y$ with some $y\neq 0$, we put $z_n=\frac{x_n}{\|x_n\|}$ if 
$\|x_n\|\neq 0$ and $z_n=0$ if $x_n=0$. It is worth mentioning that only finite $z_n$ attain zero. 
Then the sequence $z_n$ is also a Cauchy sequence in $\partial B(0,1)$ by removing the finite zeros. Let $z$ be the limit of $\{z_n\}$. Then $\{x_n\}$  converges to $yz$, because $\|x_n\|\to y$ and $\frac{x_n}{\|x_n\|}\to z$.

Comment: How exacly do you prove that $(z_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is also Cauchy? Also, if $z_n = 0$ then $(z_n)_{n=1}^\infty \notin \partial B(0,1)$. It is best just to remove zeros from the sequence.

Comment: @mechanodroid  Yes, we need to remove the zero. I will update it